# multiple screens using python

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have a python script running two big processes, when i run them both are triggered and produce the output in the same stdout. what i am looking for is , I want to print them in the different stdout(probably process1 in screen1 and prrocess2 in screen2)

```
#main.py
def proc1():
    #do something
def proc2():
    #do something
p1 = threading.Thread(target=proc1)
p2 = threading.Thread(target=proc2)
p1.start()
p2.start()
```

what i required is p1 should run in one screen and p2 should run in another screen for viewing the running log,easy understanding and debugging. Is it possible??

Answer (score 2):

If you can't change where to print the output, and it must be to stdout, then it's not possible, because the stream will be queued in the stdout buffer in an interleaving way, and there's no way to distinguish which text comes from which stream.

If you really want to see the output in real-time for two different streams on different screens, you can write the second output (or both on different files) on a file, say `output2.txt`, then on another terminal, do a live read from that file using `tail -f`.

From man page:

> The -f option causes tail to not stop when end of file is reached, but rather to wait for additional data to be appended to the input.  The -f option
>                is ignored if the standard input is a pipe, but not if it is a FIFO.

So, assuming you write the two outstreams into two different file, `output1.txt` and `output2.txt`, you can run the script in the following manner:

Screen 1:

```
python script.py
```

Screen 2 (for seeing output from thread 1):

```
tail -f output1.txt
```

Screen 3 (for seeing output from thread 2):

```
tail -f output2.txt
```

Or, if you prefer only two active screens at a time, you can just output the first thread output into the stdout.

P.S.: Actually you're not having two processes, but rather, two threads. Those are two different things, don't mix them up.

Comment: is it possible through python process then?? also, this tail -f is it possible to make it automated??

Comment: What do you mean "through python process"? And by automated, do you really understand what you mean? It would mean that as you run the script, another random terminal on your machine would suddenly show a stream of output out of nowhere. You need to run the `tail -f` command on the other screen first before running the script (create an empty file first with the same name).